# Angular: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having trouble using jQuery and jquery-ui in Angular.

I created a function, however when executing I get the error:

> $ is not defined.

I leave the stackblitz link here to see if I talked to imports or if I need other things.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dajcjv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `jquery` to do any of things you want to do. Angular does all of it out of the box.

You can bind click events to html elements using [Angular's Event Binding](https://angular.io/guide/user-input):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="#proImage.click()">Upload Image</a>
<input type="file" #proImage name="pro-image" style="display: none;" (change)="fileChanged(#proImage.files)" class="form-control" multiple>
```

And then implement`fileChanged(files: FileList)` in your component.

Also, please do not manipulate the DOM outside of Angular. Do not use JQuery to add or remove elements from the DOM. Most likely you will want to use Angular's [attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#data-binding-and-html), 
[ngFor or ngIf directives](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data). If non of these suits you use Angular's [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2).

In 99.99% of the cases you do not want to use JQuery. Please read Angular documentations, it has detailed examples and tutorials for most of this stuff.

Comment: I opted for JavaScript because I understand better. In angular could not get the desired results

Comment: I know you opted for jQuery because you are familiar with it. However, using it like that will strip you away from many important features provided by Angular out of the box, Most important is you lose lots of security protection that jQuery does not provide. If you take more time trying to understand Angular, I guarantee you will realize the benefits. :)

Comment: Do you think that with the angle I could select several images and put them in boxes correctly, without javascript?

Comment: Without JQuery, yes absolutely. You will have to write some Typescript for sure, but it will be the Angular way.

Comment: I already managed to do the function, however I can not insert the various images in the various boxes ...
can you help me?

Comment: I did this previously using `FileReader` API. example code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ay2vtu

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery with Angular, usually you misuse Angular, or not using it to its full potential. The previous answer, by Omar, explains it extensively.

However, if this is some legacy code, and you need it straight away, jquery should be added to "scripts" in angular.json file.

```
"scripts": ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"]
```

Next you want to import it in a different way, from hello.component.

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

Declaring it is not necessary:

```
declare var $: any;
```

[Final code.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ncfta)

Comment: I opted for JavaScript because I understand better. In angular could not get the desired results

Comment: I tested your version and by clicking the button I get it even though the $ is not declared

Comment: Okay, I got it. 
My version was solving the problem with adding jquery, the problem you are describing is missuse of Angular. Your way of btn click is non-Angular approach, and HelloComponent doesn't work properly. 

Try the same link I've aadded, and take a look at the AppComponent and button click. 

However this has to be recreated in an Angular way, otherwise you'll be facing issue after issue. 

In case you might need instructions on that matter, create another question with app description, so we could help you with the correct structure.

Comment: I will then create a new question, thanks for the help!